# Capturing a email genetating via javascript

Tags: javascript, php, regex, trim, utf8-decode

I'm using "simplehtmldom" to captured the elements.

I want to capture the email address from the following [image: email capture]

the email is generating with javascript and It was decoded. So I know I can not capture the email.

I noticed, I couldn't select the "output" or It's child element for some reasons.

```
 $myemail = $item->find ('#field_11 .output');
```

So I captured the whole div by following method

```
$myemail = $item->find ('#field_11');
```

and which out puts the following result.

[image: Firebug screenshot]

I guess If I remove the `<!--` I'll able to print the value. I was trying to trim the `<!--` by follwing method but none of them work

```
trim($myemail, "!--//");

trim(strip_tags($myemail), "!--//");

trim(htmlentities($myemail), "!--//");
```

I was trying to decode the result by following functions but none of them work (I guess using REGEX I can extract the email after decode)

> html_entity_decode
>
> htmlspecialchars_decode
>
> utf8_decode

Could anyone help me to achieve what I want? Please ignore if any of my method distract you from providing a right solution.

Answer (score 0):

it's URL encoding

```
echo rawurldecode("%69%6E%66");
```

result

> inf